# Ascending/Resetting Integer Values from MultiIndex Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [('a', 1990),('a', 1994),('a',1996),('b',1992),('b',1997),('c',2001)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names = ['Type', 'Year'])
vals = ['This','That','SomeName','This','SomeOtherName','SomeThirdName']
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=index, columns=['Whatev'])


df
Out[3]: 
                  Whatev
Type Year               
a    1990           This
     1994           That
     1996       SomeName
b    1992           This
     1997  SomeOtherName
c    2001  SomeThirdName
```

And I'd like to add a column of ascending integers corresponding to 'Year' that resets for each 'Type', like so:

```
                  Whatev  IndexInt
Type Year                         
a    1990           This         1
     1994           That         2
     1996       SomeName         3
b    1992           This         1
     1997  SomeOtherName         2
c    2001  SomeThirdName         1
```

Here's my current method:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
unique_loc = []
for name, group in grouped:
    unique_loc += range(1,len(group)+1)
joined['IndexInt'] = unique_loc
```

But this seems ugly and convoluted to me, and I imagine it could get slow on the ~50 million row dataframe that I'm working with.  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby(level=0)` + [cumcount()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
In [7]: df['IndexInt'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
                  Whatev  IndexInt
Type Year
a    1990           This         1
     1994           That         2
     1996       SomeName         3
b    1992           This         1
     1997  SomeOtherName         2
c    2001  SomeThirdName         1
```

Comment: Aargh, too fast.  Anyway, if all goes according to plan, we should soon have a companion to `cumcount` (maybe named `enumerate`), which will give the number of the group, and so between the two they'll completely encode the key information.

Comment: @DSM, that sounds fantastic! Where can i read about this? Is there a corresponding PR?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11642); the PR will probably be pushed later this week.  Don't know if it'll make it into 0.19 or not.

Comment: @DSM, that's really a nice feature! Thank you for the link! BTW  do you know when will 0.18.2 be released?